# Dojo: defining Select-like widget with Options declaratively

Tags: javascript, dojo

The goal is to write custom widget similar to Select with options. Options should be able to be specified declarative. Example:

```
<div data-dojo-type="MySelect"> 
  <span class="my-select-option" data-dojo-type="MySelectOption>Foo</span>
  <span class="my-select-option" data-dojo-type="MySelectOption>Bar</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that all `<span>`s get overwritten and removed. What is the way to handle them correctly inside `MySelect`'s JavaScript file?

Comment: @GibboK I have read this article https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/writingWidgets.html I also read article about life-circles of the widget. At this point I think it is impossible (Dojo is made other way). So either you define a template, or add content pragmatically.

Comment: You can decoratively configure your custom widget using data-dojo-props, or use a programmatic approach. Both are working just fine. Please reference to my answer for more information. If I could help in smt else, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data-dojo-props` together with `dojo/parser` to decoratively configure your custom widget.

Here a quick example for a possible markup, please note:

- Use `data-dojo-type` to specify your custom "class" for your widget.
- Use `data-dojo-props` to pass to the constructor any sort of configuration information upon instantiation.

`data-dojo-props` is a HTML5 data attributes and works with the latest version of Dojo.

Markup in your HTML:

```
<div id="instanceId" data-dojo-type="nameSpace/class" data-dojo-props="data: 'some data'"></div>
```

This reading is a good start:

https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/declarative/

For more information about parsing:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/parser.html